# How to center horizontally container cards with bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My objective is to center my container contains all cards.
I using boostrap 4 and tried all things like `justify-content-center` but there is problem with the last line.
Please see my snippet code in fullscreen.

How to center horizontally container ? (like margin: 0 auto ?)

Image: the problem there are too spacing on right.

[image]
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmFna.png)

```css
.card-custom {
  max-width: 128px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The container and cards are centered with `justify-content-center` https://www.codeply.com/go/7vCdEHWQ8M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need our `justify-content` to first assign `center` property which will bring all our cards in the center and then to assign property of `flex-start`.

This is not possible to assign to just 1 box.

So I added another box i.e. `<div class="flex-left">`

> Class `outerContainer`(Black Border) is assigned property of `justify-content:center`

It will just center the box `flex-left` like this

[image]

> Class `flex-left` has property of `flex-wrap:wrap;` which will push the overflowing card to next line, which will be on the left hence `justify-content:flex-start` is not required

But now the problem is, the will not be aligned in the center if cards starts moving to the next line.

This is what we **don't want**:

[image]

This is what **we want**:
[image]

I have added `media-queries` to it.
and assigned property of `margin-left` to it.

### **margin-left Calculation**

`margin-left:(50% - (([card_margin * 2] + [card_width]) / 2))`

First we push `float-left` by 50% and then bring back, half of the remaining width of `float-left`.

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.outerContainer {
  margin-top: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .flex-left {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 310px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  .flex-left {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 250px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 484px) {
  .flex-left {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 185px)
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 363px) {
  .flex-left {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 125px)
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row outerContainer">
    <div class="flex-left">
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx but if you resize your web browser to show 4 cards in first line and 2 cards on second line, the 2 cards are center. I would  like this 2 cards be placed on left.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a `.row` (which is meant only to contain `col-*`) use `d-flex` and `justify-content-center`. The `container` is already centered. Also, why not use `container-fluid` instead of `container` since `container-fluid` is 100% width.

https://www.codeply.com/go/7vCdEHWQ8M

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex mt-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
      <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
        <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/7vCdEHWQ8M

Comment: Thank for your proposal but your cards aren't staked. In your example all cards are only one line.

Comment: Where does your question state that you want the cards stacked? Your question states that you want them centered. "How to center horizontally container?" Please clarify the question. If you want them in rows/columns then you should contain the cards inside the Bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 2):

One easy responsive solution is to use the grid system.

```css
.card-custom {
  max-width: 128px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
          <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card card-custom ">
        <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
          <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```